# Errors Drawing simple circuits with circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I get errors drawing electronic circuits from the circuitikz manual.
However I have no problem drawing fairly complex logic circuits.

Heres a sample:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to[R, *-] (2,0);
    \end{circuitikz}   
\end{document}
```

Errors:

```
line 5: Undefined control sequence. \draw (0,0) to[R, *-] (2,0)
line 5: Undefined control sequence. \draw (0,0) to[R, *-] (2,0)
line 5: Missing number, treated as zero. \draw (0,0) to[R, *-] (2,0)
line 5: Undefined control sequence. \draw (0,0) to[R, *-] (2,0)
```

Log file dump:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.3.16)  13 AUG 2017 18:08
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**ccts.tex
(./ccts.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 2 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cls
Document Class: standalone 2012/09/15 v1.1b Class to compile TeX sub-files stan
dalone
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2014/05/25 v2.7 package option processing (HA)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks14
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count79
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/05/25 v2.7 key=value parser (HA)
))
\sa@internal=\count80

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cfg
File: standalone.cfg 2012/09/15 v1.1b Default configuration file for 'standalon
e' class
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count81
\c@section=\count82
\c@subsection=\count83
\c@subsubsection=\count84
\c@paragraph=\count85
\c@subparagraph=\count86
\c@figure=\count87
\c@table=\count88
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
\sa@box=\box26
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/circuitikz/tex/circuitikz.sty
Package: circuitikz 2017/05/01{} The CircuiTikz circuit drawing package version
 0.8.2

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks16
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen103
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen104

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.t
ex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box27
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
Package: pgfrcs 2013/12/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.28)
))
Package: pgf 2013/12/18 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2014/04/25 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count89
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen105
\Gin@req@width=\dimen106
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2013/11/30 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.47)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks17
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks18

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.t
ex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks19
))
\pgf@x=\dimen107
\pgf@y=\dimen108
\pgf@xa=\dimen109
\pgf@ya=\dimen110
\pgf@xb=\dimen111
\pgf@yb=\dimen112
\pgf@xc=\dimen113
\pgf@yc=\dimen114
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count90
\c@pgf@countb=\count91
\c@pgf@countc=\count92
\c@pgf@countd=\count93
\t@pgf@toka=\toks20
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks21
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks22
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2013/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.33)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.de
f
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2013/10/10  (rcs-revision 1.13)
)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.
tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count94
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count95
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.
tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1337.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1341.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1355.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1358.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1359.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1360.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen115
\pgfmath@count=\count96
\pgfmath@box=\box28
\pgfmath@toks=\toks23
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks24
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks25
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonomet
ric.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison
.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerari
thmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count97
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.te
x
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.27)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen116
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen117
\pgf@picminy=\dimen118
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen119
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen120
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen121
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen122
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen123
\pgf@xx=\dimen124
\pgf@xy=\dimen125
\pgf@yx=\dimen126
\pgf@yy=\dimen127
\pgf@zx=\dimen128
\pgf@zy=\dimen129
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.
code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.29)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen130
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen131
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code
.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2013/12/13  (rcs-revision 1.23)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen132
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen133
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.te
x
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2013/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.44)
\pgfpic=\box29
\pgf@hbox=\box30
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box31
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count98
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.c
ode.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2013/09/19  (rcs-revision 1.11)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen134
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformation
s.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2013/10/10  (rcs-revision 1.17)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen135
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen136
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen137
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.t
ex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing
.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.te
x
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2013/11/07  (rcs-revision 1.40)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen138
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@max=\dimen139
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count99
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.18)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.
tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box32
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.te
x
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2013/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.c
ode.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2013/09/30  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.
tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2013/11/07  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2013/10/31  (rcs-revision 1.34)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box33
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2013/07/31  (rcs-revision 1.12)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65
.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen140
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen141
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18
.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.1)
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.25)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen142
\pgffor@skip=\dimen143
\pgffor@stack=\toks26
\pgffor@toks=\toks27
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers
.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2013/08/31 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count100
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen144
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen145
\tikz@lasty=\dimen146
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen147
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen148
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen149
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen150
\tikz@figbox=\box34
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box35
\tikz@tempbox=\box36
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box37
\tikztreelevel=\count101
\tikznumberofchildren=\count102
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count103
\tikz@fig@count=\count104

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2013/09/17  (rcs-revision 1.8)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count105
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count106
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count107
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count108

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.2)
)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibrarycalc.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex 2013/07/15 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.9)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.code.
tex
File: pgflibraryarrows.code.tex 2013/09/23 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.16)
\arrowsize=\dimen151
) (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/circuitikz/tex/pgfcirc.defines.tex
\pgf@circ@res@up=\dimen152
\pgf@circ@res@down=\dimen153
\pgf@circ@res@zero=\dimen154
\pgf@circ@res@left=\dimen155
\pgf@circ@res@right=\dimen156
\pgf@circ@res@other=\dimen157
\pgf@circ@res@step=\dimen158
\pgf@circ@res@temp=\dimen159
\pgfstartlinewidth=\dimen160
\pgf@circ@Rlen=\dimen161
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/circuitikz/tex/pgfcircutils.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/circuitikz/tex/pgfcircshapes.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/circuitikz/tex/pgfcircmonopoles.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/circuitikz/tex/pgfcircbipoles.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/circuitikz/tex/pgfcirctripoles.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/circuitikz/tex/pgfcircquadpoles.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/circuitikz/tex/pgfcirclabel.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/circuitikz/tex/pgfcircvoltage.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/circuitikz/tex/pgfcirccurrent.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/circuitikz/tex/pgfcircpath.tex)) (./ccts.aux)
\openout1 = `ccts.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.

ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count109
\scratchdimen=\dimen162
\scratchbox=\box38
\nofMPsegments=\count110
\nofMParguments=\count111
\everyMPshowfont=\toks28
\MPscratchCnt=\count112
\MPscratchDim=\dimen163
\MPnumerator=\count113
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count114
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks29
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
Package: grfext 2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 452.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgf@sh@bg@resistorshape ...sformationadjustments 
                                                  \pgfmathsetlength {\pgf@ci...
l.5         \draw (0,0) to[R, *-] (2,0)
                                       ;
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...fhorizontaltransformationadjustment 
                                                  *0.5*\pgflinewidth 
l.5         \draw (0,0) to[R, *-] (2,0)
                                       ;
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.5         \draw (0,0) to[R, *-] (2,0)
                                       ;
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...fhorizontaltransformationadjustment 
                                                  *0.5*\pgflinewidth 
l.5         \draw (0,0) to[R, *-] (2,0)
                                       ;
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.5         \draw (0,0) to[R, *-] (2,0)
                                       ;
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

[1

] (./ccts.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 18552 strings out of 495020
 444640 string characters out of 6181324
 561905 words of memory out of 5000000
 21521 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 62i,7n,56p,423b,672s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on ccts.pdf (1 page, 1277 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 11 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 7 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 13 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)


    line 6: Missing number, treated as zero. \draw (0,0) to[R, *-] (2,0)
```

Comment: That example works fine with TeX Live 2016 at least (I haven't upgraded to TL17 yet). TL16 has version 3.0.1a of TikZ/`pgf`, while your log seems to indicate that you have 3.0.0. I do not know if that specifically is the problem, but it could be that upgrading your LaTeX distribution will solve this. Your version of `circuitikz` is from 2017, so surely newer than TeX Live 2015, that you're using.

Comment: `\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}` instead of `\usepackage{circuitikz}` should help?

Comment: The full name of the missing macro is `\pgfhorizontaltransformationadjustment` which comes from tikz.  Try updating your packages.